# how do I use logback-access for capturing the HTTP logs with weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c, access-log

I have followed the logback-access documentation https://logback.qos.ch/access.html  and able to customize the http access logs in tomcat server.

similarly how do I use logback-access with web logic server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this component does not provide any integration with WebLogic Server. Maybe you can try to implement your own integration starting with a javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper class.
You should know that WebLogic Server enables extending access log information quite easily.
This [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD207) will help you.